# Python how to delete a line in a table

Tags: python

I using Python and a function give me this output:

```
 [['2', 'prod1', 'Ela - Available'], ['2', 'prod1', 'Base - Replication logs']]
```

My goal it's to delete all lines contains "Available" with Python

So my goal it's to have:

```
[['2', 'prod1', 'Base - Replication logs']]
```

Comment: Can you show your attempts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
data = [['2', 'prod1', 'Ela - Available'], ['2', 'prod1', 'Base - Replication logs']]
output  = [line for line in data if not 'Available' in str(line)]
print(output)
[['2', 'prod1', 'Base - Replication logs']]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> l = [['2', 'prod1', 'Ela - Available'], ['2', 'prod1', 'Base - Replication logs']]
>>> filter(lambda x: not any('Available' in y for y in x), l)
[['2', 'prod1', 'Base - Replication logs']]
```